# Linear map composition is zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a following problem and I don't know how should I start solving it:

Let $L$ be a linear map: $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ such that $L^3(v) = \overrightarrow{0}$ for every $v$ from $\mathbb R^2$. Show that $L^2(v) = \overrightarrow{0}$ for every $v$ from $\mathbb R^2$.

It seems obvious - if the linear map is scaling transformation, then the only way to get only zeroes at the end is to scale by $0$ three times. But how to prove it in formal way?

Answer (score 3):

Write $L^3(v) = L^2(L(v))$. If $\dim L(\mathbb{R}^2) = 0$ for all $v$ then $L=0$ and $L^2(v)=0$ for all $v$. If $\dim L(\mathbb{R}^2) = 2$, then $L$ is invertible, which cannot be since then $L^3$ would be invertible. Otherwise $\dim L(\mathbb{R}^2) = 1$, say $L(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the span of $\{x\}$. It suffices to show $x \in \ker L$, so that anything not killed by $L$ gets killed by the second application of $L$. If not, i.e. $L(x) \neq 0$, then $L(x)=cx$ for some $c \neq 0$ since the image of $L$ is spanned by $x$. But then $L^3(x) = c^3 x \neq 0$, a contradiction. Thus it must be that $L(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial of $L$ is a divisor of $x^3$, and hence its only ireducible factor is  $x$. As the characteristic polynomial of $L$ has the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial and has degree $2$, it is $x^2$. Then use Hamilton-Cayley.